# How to delete a file with the Pentaho REST API

Tags: rest, pentaho

My Pentaho REST API is working expected for one feature : delete folder or file, I tried this syntax and some others but it didn't work :

PUT method : http://my-server/pentaho/api/repo/files/delete/public:basic.xml

I tried to change the method (DELETE) and other syntax but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0R0/070/010/0A0/0O0) you `PUT` to:

```
/repo/files/delete
```

or

```
/repo/files/deletepermanent
```

with the body:

> A comma-separated list of the files to be moved to the trash folder

or

> A comma-separated list of the files to be deleted

Comment: Thanks for helping, I saw the documentation on the Pentaho site but finally I made this working with a curl command **curl -u admin:password -X PUT -d 750c76de-4e1e-4fff-8c99-4d2e08b838de http://my_server/pentaho/api/repo/files/delete**, I was using postman and I didn't knew where I should write my list of files

Comment: Just FYI, it's not an either/or for delete versus deletepermanent. You have to delete before you can deletepermanent.

Answer (score 1):

Your PUT request should be :

```
http://servername.domain.com:8080/pentaho/api/repo/files/delete
```

and in the request body you need to put ID of deleted file.
This ID you can get making request like :

```
http://servername.domain.com:8080/pentaho/api/repo/files/home/karp/ARCH/children?locale=en
```

Answer will be similar to :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<repositoryFileDtoes>
    <repositoryFileDto>
        <aclNode>false</aclNode>
        <createdDate>1579701212208</createdDate>
        <fileSize>8923</fileSize>
        <folder>false</folder>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <id>6f43abcc-0e05-4dbe-8bf9-fc383a9e7983</id>
        <lastModifiedDate>1579701212208</lastModifiedDate>
        <locale>pl</locale>
        <localePropertiesMapEntries>
                <locale>default</locale>
                <properties>
                        <key>file.title</key>
                        <value>Ankieta_po</value>
                </properties>
                <properties>
                        <key>jcr:primaryType</key>
                        <value>nt:unstructured</value>
                </properties>
                <properties>
                        <key>title</key>
                        <value>Ankieta_po</value>
                </properties>
        </localePropertiesMapEntries>
        <locked>false</locked>
        <name>Ankieta_po.prpt</name>
        <notSchedulable>false</notSchedulable>
        <ownerType>-1</ownerType>
        <path>/home/karp/ARCH/Ankieta_po.prpt</path>
        <title>Ankieta_po</title>
        <versionCommentEnabled>false</versionCommentEnabled>
        <versionId>1.1</versionId>
        <versioned>true</versioned>
        <versioningEnabled>false</versioningEnabled>
    </repositoryFileDto>
</repositoryFileDtoes>
```

So , your request should looks like this (below from Postman) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnPZw.png)